# Navigation Not Responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a navigation more mobile friendly, and everything is working as expected when the screen resolution is greater than 767px.  Everything is centered.

When I go less than 767px, it becomes misaligned and looks very weird.

Here is my CSS:

```
#nav{
    text-align: center;
    max-width:997px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:14px 10px 15px;
}
#nav ul{    padding:0;  margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav:after{
    content:''; display:block;  clear:both;
}
#nav > ul > li{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 0 73px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav > ul > li:first-child{margin:0;}
#nav a{color:#d1d1d1;}
#nav> ul > li> a:hover,
#nav> ul > .active > a{
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav .drop{
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-5px;
    background:#2c2c2c;
    min-width:125px;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    #nav > ul > li{
        float:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0 20px 5px;
    }
    #nav .drop{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        position:static;
        padding:5px 5px 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
          <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HabboValley</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Community</a>
                <ul class="drop">
                  <li><a href="team.php">Meet The Team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="jobs.php">Jobs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Radio/Events</a>
                <ul class="drop">
                  <li><a href="reqline.php">Request Line</a></li>
                  <li><a href="radio.php">Radio Timetable</a></li>
                  <li><a href="events.php">Event Timetable</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Resources</a>
                <ul class="drop">
                  <li><a href="#">Guides (Coming Soon)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">News (Coming Soon)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Goodies (Coming Soon)</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://habbovalley.com/forum" target="_blank">Forum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

Screenshot of screen LARGER than 767px: http://prntscr.com/fcir4u

Screenshot of screen SMALLER than 767px: http://prntscr.com/fcirb5

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should create different break-points for your css so it will display properly.And how is your sub menu works? I tried to click and hover on the menus but your sub menu wont display. Anyway, here is a short guide to fix your style. And as what I read in **Bootstrap** the ideal way is **Mobile First**.

*Design your page first on how it will look like in the small devices.*

This tag is from Pedro Ferrari in [TeamTreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/are-there-standard-media-query-break-points).

```
/*==================================================
=            Bootstrap 3 Media Queries             =
==================================================*/




    /*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

    }



    /*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    }
```